# Custom Popover Background Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, background, uipopovercontroller

I made a popover containing sectioned tableView with some background. I want to remove that thin vertical border line, which is present on sides between two sections.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code on how you are adding that TableVIew ? :)

Comment: does tableview have background or the view ?

Comment: I am having tableView Controller Class. Its BackgroundView is set to nil & BackgroundColor to clear. As i need to add this to popover controller, which in turn would be having translucent image as background.

Answer (score 0):

set `view`'s background color or image to your custom color/image then and set `tableview`'s background to nil. It should work.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

         //background image
        self.view.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];

        //table background image, mytableview should be your tableView's name you can try self.tableView if you have not set/delegate anything to it.
        self.mytableView.backgroundView = nil;
}
```